Update source SQL Server table with data from another table
How can I update a source SQL Server table with data from another table if the data is not a one-to-one relationship?
For example, the target table - in which the data needs to be entered into, looks like this:
target table has col1 with one row each for 'a' and 'b'
And this is the table from where the data needs to be picked up - source table
this table has 2 rows for record 'a' and 3 records for 'b' in col1
The goal is for the target table to have a total of 5 rows with data for col2, col3, col4 updated from the source table with all the other fields repeated.
I have tried:
UPDATE <table>
SET <columns> 
FROM 
    (SELECT <cols> FROM <sourcetable>
     WHERE <clause>)

However, this only picks up the first row for 'a' from the source table and updates the target table. the second row for 'a' is ignored.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Please show (not as an image) both sample data and desired results.

You can't update and create new rows, for that you need an insert + update or merge
